# Not insert but upsert if document is not found

Tags: javascript, validation, meteor, input

What I need is to check if company did not add name insert company name else update company name. In my project, user after registration can complete profile completly. When user fills "company name" input and clicks save button, the company name should be added to list of companies, if user changes the name of company, it should be changed also from list of companies. Here my code
User form html:

```
 <template name="userFormEdit">
  <form class="form new-company">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="companyName">Comapany Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="companyName" id="companyName"     placeholder="" value="{{companyName}}">
    </div>
  </form
</template>


<div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
        <h2>Portfolio</h2>
        <h4>What we have created</h4>
        <div class="row text-center">
            {{ #each companyProfile }}
            {{> companyView }}
            {{/each }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<template name="companyView">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="..." alt="Paris">
            <p><strong>{{companyName}}</strong></p>
            <p>Yes, we built Paris</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And this is .js file:

```
currentUserProfile = new Meteor.Collection('userprofile');
//In client
Template.userFormEdit.events({
        'submit .new-company' : function(event){
            var companyNameVar = event.target.companyName.value;
            currentUserProfile.update(this._id,{$set: {companyName: companyNameVar}});
        }
    });

Template.homepage.helpers({
        companyProfile: function(){
            return currentUserProfile.find();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think this check is better and easier to complete with SQL-query on server side. User clicks 'Save' button, form data sent to server and your php(or something)-script  inserts or replaces company name to database.

Comment: @Banzay hes using Meteor wich use Javascritp on the server (nodejs) and Mongo No-SQL for the db,  [check it out](http://meteor.com/) its a cool framework =D

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Can't you just use `upsert` instead of update? what do you mean by "two events"?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor has built in [upsert](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/upsert) for collections. You can use that.